# Why didn't Rip Hunter recruit The Flash and Green Arrow on the team?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In *Legends of Tomorrow*, Rip Hunter recruits heroes on to his team: The Atom, White Canary, Firestorm, Hawkman, Hawkgirl, Captain Cold and Heatwave to stop Vandal Savage from taking over the world. Rip choose specific people to help him:

> I could have chosen any time and any place. Of all the people who ever lived, I chose you eight. I certainly hope that you won't let me, and the world, down.

But there are other heroes he could have included with them, such as Barry Allen (aka The Flash) and Oliver Queen (aka The Green Arrow) but he only choose these people

Why didn't Rip Hunter recruit The Flash and Green Arrow on the team?

Answer (score 6):

Other than Kendra and Carter, who are needed on the team for self-evident reasons, the only indication we're given for how Rip chose the rest of the Legends is in his confession near the end of the first episode:

> **Rip:**  I chose you all because, a hundred years from now, your lives have minimal effect on the recorded timeline. I needed your help without disturbing the history of 2166.
>
> <sup>*Legends of Tomorrow* Season 1 Episode 1: "Pilot, Part 1"</sup>

This is clearly an oversimplification, since each member of the team does bring skills to the table. However, the reason for choosing - for example - Ray Palmer over Oliver Queen would seem to be this one.

So, it would seem that Barry and Oliver are just more important to the timeline than the others are. Although we don't know much about Arrowverse history post-2016, there is some limited evidence for this:

- I'm guessing at the end of the current season of *Arrow*, but Oliver appears instrumental in preventing Hive from doing some Bad Things in Star City
- Oliver is also instrumental in Grant Wilson's (Deathstroke's son's) rise and fall, as seen in the *Legends of Tomorrow* episode "Star City 2046"<sup>1</sup>
- Barry is an *extremely* public figure in Eobard Thawne's future, though the exact impact of his actions is unknown

---

<sup>1</sup> This may not be a good example, since it's unclear to what extent the events of that episode were caused by Ray and Sara being removed from the timeline. In the episode, Oliver suggests that their absence was very relevant to the Bad Future, but that would seem to contradict Rip's statement that they were unimportant. YMMV.

Comment: barry and oliver unimportant not true

Comment: @AndrewCasali I agree, and that's my point. Barry and Oliver *are* important; Ray and Sara are less important

Comment: but with Kendra carter ray Sara snart Rory jax martin along with Barry and Oliver that would a better team to stop savage

Comment: @AndrewCasali Unless they fail (and both Barry and Oliver *have* failed against Savage before, in "Legends of Today"/"Legends of Yesterday"), in which case Rip has just robbed the timeline of two Very Important People. Rip is thinking strategically, weighing the benefit of different potential team members against the consequences of their failure

Comment: they would not fail barry and oliver can be extra help to the whole team

Comment: @JasonBaker: if I understood correctly the episodes with their baby selves, the Legends will not come back to the time they left if they succeed in their mission. So removing the Flash and Arrow for some time does have impact, even in case of success.

Comment: @Taladris That wasn't how I interpreted the show's approach to time, but I'll have to think on it

Comment: @JasonBarker: I was thinking about the scene where Martin Stein and Rip Hunter are talking about Martin's wife not remembering him and the consequences of their adventures on their life when they'll be back. I recognize I am not sure I understood the dialogue though.